# How to enforce a returned pandas dataframe to be a view so that I can perform transformation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe named `merge` and looks like the following:

```
filepath                        timestamp  label_x  label_y X   Y   W   H
S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0274    -----   empty   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0275    -----   empty   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0276    -----   empty   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0277    -----   empty   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Some timestamps are missing, I would like to fetch timestamps from image metadata(location is indicated by `filepath` column). As you can see, filepath contains folders starting with name `S6`. These folders are supposed be from `S1` to `S6` but currenly I only folders `S1` and `S2`. I would like to slicing those folders out and perform transformations:

```
import PIL.Image
def transformation(row):
    try:
        img=PIL.Image.open(path0/row["filepath"])
        row["timestamp"]=img._getexif()[306]
        return row
    except:
        return 
merge[ (merge["timestamp"]=='-----')& (merge["filepath"].str.startswith("S1") | merge["filepath"].str.startswith("S2")) ].apply(transformation, axis=1)
```

But this doesn't work because the slicing operation fundamentally returns me a copy:

```
>>>merge[(merge["timestamp"]=='-----')& (merge["filepath"].str.startswith("S1") | merge["filepath"].str.startswith("S2")) ]._is_view
>>>False
```

How can I change the behaviour of pandas to get a view?

Comment: `merge.loc[((merge['timestamp']=='-----') & (merge['filepath'].str.startswith('S1') | merge['filepath'].str.startswith('S2')))]._is_view` yield False either. Any other way? @ Chris

Answer (score 0):

you can apply your function and use update but you need to return a series in your function:

```
# sample df
# df = pd.read_clipboard()
# df.iloc[0:1, 1] = 'some value'

                           filepath   timestamp label_x  label_y   X   Y   W  \
0  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0274  some value   empty      NaN NaN NaN NaN   
1  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0275       -----   empty      NaN NaN NaN NaN   
2  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0276       -----   empty      NaN NaN NaN NaN   
3  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0277       -----   empty      NaN NaN NaN NaN   

    H  
0 NaN  
1 NaN  
2 NaN  
3 NaN
```

now use `update` and `apply` with `loc`

```
# your function
def myFunc(row):
    row['timestamp'] = 'some new value' # set new value to timestamp
    return row['timestamp'] # return a series

# use update and apply your function 
df['timestamp'].update(df.loc[2:3].apply(myFunc, axis=1))
# you would change df.loc[2:3] to your boolean
# df.loc[((df["timestamp"]=='-----') & (df['filepath'].str.startswith('S1') | df['filepath'].str.startswith('S2')))]
```

Out

```
                           filepath       timestamp label_x  label_y   X   Y  \
0  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0274      some value   empty      NaN NaN NaN   
1  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0275           -----   empty      NaN NaN NaN   
2  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0276  some new value   empty      NaN NaN NaN   
3  S6/N11/N11_R1/S6_N11_R1_IMAG0277  some new value   empty      NaN NaN NaN   

    W   H  
0 NaN NaN  
1 NaN NaN  
2 NaN NaN  
3 NaN NaN
```